# opinion about a query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

If I have this piece of schema:

```
Doctor(license_no, doctor_name, specialty)

Patient(pat_id, pat_name, pat_address, pat_phone, date_of_birth)

Visit(license_no, pat_id, date, type, diagnosis, charge)
```

and I want to get the amount of money that Dr. Davy Jones has earned,
is the following query logically right? N.B it's running in SQL

```
SELECT SUM(charge)
FROM   Visit v INNER JOIN Doctor d
ON  (d.licence_no = v.licence_no AND doctor_name = 'davy jones')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes :)

Just made a quick test.

Answer (score 5):

I'd write it slightly different to account for the case where davy jones has seen no patients.

```
SELECT SUM(v.charge)
    FROM Doctor d
        LEFT JOIN Visit v
            ON d.license_no = v.license_no
    WHERE d.doctor_name = 'davy jones';
```

Comment: @MohamedAbdelHakim The primary change is that I'm using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER and I moved the test for doctor_name to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since you alias the table "Visit" to "v" you should also use the alias when specifying the column `(v.charge)`. Also your inner join condition should specify only the join condition, and not the limiting clause, which should be specified as a `WHERE` condition. See this example:

```
SELECT SUM(v.charge)
FROM Visit v INNER JOIN Doctor d
ON (d.licence_no = v.licence_no)
WHERE d.doctor_name = 'davy jones';
```